# Какой вид грамматической связи в составных сказуемых?

Tags: грамматика

Скажите, пожалуйста, какой вид связи в составных сказуемых, например: могу писать, стало темно. Это подчинительная связь, там есть главное и зависимое слово?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу писать, стало темно - это словосочетания, но не свободные, а слитные, связь - примыкание.

[Какие сочетания слов не являются словосочетаниями? | genon.ru](http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=79f079b0-5d1e-4e30-8670-c117e48da245)

Синтаксически несвободные (цельные) словосочетания — это соединение слов, в котором грамматически зависимое слово является главным по смыслу, а грамматически главное слово является недостаточным с точки зрения семантики (информации). Синтаксически несвободные словосочетания не разлагаются на составные части. В предложении синтаксически цельные словосочетания являются одним членом предложения: два дома, несколько студентов, мало времени.
Модели несвободных (цельных) словосочетаний:

1. Количественно-именные словосочетания ( три карандаша, двое ребят, столько людей, много машин, множество книг).
2. Словосочетания со значением избирательности (один из нас, каждый из присутствующих, некоторые из учеников, кто-то из ребят).
3. Словосочетания с метафорическим значением.
   Главное слово употреблено в переносном значении и называет то, на что похож предмет, зависимое слово — прямое название предмета:серп месяца, шапка кудрей, зеркало реки, пламень уст (С. Есенин), листьев медь (С. Есенин), костёр рябины (С. Есенин).
4. Словосочетания со значением неопределённости.
   Главное слово — неопределённое местоимение, зависимое — согласуемое прилагательное, причастие: что-то неприятное, кто-то незнакомый, некто сидящий.
5. Словосочетания со значением совместности (брат с сестрой, Коля с товарищем).
6. Контекстуально-цельные словосочетания.
   Цельность их возникает только в контексте предложения или сложного словосочетания: умный человек сумеет разобраться в этом; девушка с голубыми глазами, человек высокого роста.
7. **Словосочетания в составных сказуемых, включающие в себя вспомогательные глаголы, глаголы-связки или другие вспомогательные компоненты**: Он начал рассказывать о приключениях в джунглях Амазонки; Мы хотим вам помочь; Она выглядела усталой.

Как правило, в школьной традиции выделяют два основных вида синтаксической связи — сочинительную и подчинительную. В лингвистической литературе принято говорить о том, что синтаксические связи бывают предикативные и непредикативные, и внутри последних разграничиваются сочинение и подчинение.

Предикативная связь, или координация (от лат. со (cum) ‘совместно’ и ordinatio ‘упорядочение’) — такая синтаксическая связь, при которой существует двусторонняя зависимость между словами. В данном отношении находятся в предложении его главные члены — подлежащее и сказуемое. Эту связь нельзя отнести к подчинительной, поскольку оба элемента языка, связанные таким образом, одновременно главные и зависимые: это можно назвать взаимным подчинением, или координацией. Так, сказуемое часто формально уподобляется подлежащему в некоторых грамматических категориях (числе, лице, роде, падеже), но при этом само сказуемое требует от подлежащего определенной грамматической формы — именительного падежа.

В некоторых случаях эта связь может быть формально не выражена при помощи грамматических показателей и будет проявляться за счет особого интонационного оформления и порядка слов в предложении: Они родом из Псковской губернии; Наша задача — формировать успешных молодых людей; Готовить еду всем вместе очень весело; Убеждать его — напрасный труд и т.п.

Подробнее здесь: [Предикативная связь. Вопрос о предикативном согласовании. Отличие предикативной связи от подчинительной. | webkonspect.com](http://webkonspect.com/?id=15368&labelid=145371&room=profile)

Comment: Спасибо, это как раз то, что мне было непонятно.

Answer (score 2):

Грамматическая связь рассматривается только в словосочетаниях (от главного слова ставится вопрос к зависимому).

Составные сказуемые не образуют словосочетания.

См.: **[Как выражается грамматическая связь слов в словосочетании?](http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=491a8f67-030a-4c67-a9c1-d249dac7c33c)**

Comment: Но разве не все слова связаны друг с другом, если они члены предложения. Например, в таком примере: Небо стало темным. Небо стало темное. Здесь именная часть согласуется по роду и числу и падеж может меняться (управление?).

Comment: Извините, еще один вопрос: предикативную связь  можно назвать грамматической (или синтаксической). Можно сказать, что предикативная связь - это особый вид грамматической связи?

Comment: Спасибо, я прочитала ссылку, но вот что мне осталось непонятным: в несвободных сочетаниях существует грамматическая связь? Например: я умею (что делать?) читать. Умею - грамматически главное слово, читать - грамматически зависимое слово. Это так? А каков вид этой связи? И еще: умея читать, умеющий читать - это тоже несвободные сочетания? Извините за большое количество вопросов, но очень хочется разобраться.

Comment: Арина, задавайте вопросы как новые, не уточняйте возникшие параллельные нюансы в комментах. И ждите ответов Людмилы - у неё университет за плечами, она замечательно знает всю "матчасть", а я редактор-практик.

Comment: Хорошо, извините, просто  мне показалось неудобным задавать вопрос на ту же самую тему.